# Clear polling timeout in javascript or angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polling

```
function scan (id) {    
    $http({
            method: "POST",
            url:( "url"),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: $.param({id: id}),
        })
            .then(scanComplete)
            .catch(function(message) {
                throw new Error("XHR Failed ",message);
            });

        function scanComplete(response, status, headers, config) {
            //do something , show errors, popup , call to other functions
        }
  setTimeout(function() {scan())}, 1000);
}
```

this is my function to polling for checking if there are new notification in the database for example.

I don't clear the timeout at all and don't use the $timeout .  is it mistake ? is it cause to chrome problem like freezing or CPU overhead?

how can I clear and how can I check that I really cleared it

all the functions and ui aspects . are from angular service/factory  without controller (besides the service call)

Comment: You haven't shared you ajax code, but you should invoke `setTimeout` and in that `scan` method only after the success or failure of ajax call.

Comment: @gurvinder372 . updated my code

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke again only in the `scanComplete` function

```
function scanComplete(response, status, headers, config) {
    //do something , show errors, popup , call to other functions
    setTimeout( scan, 1000); //invoke after your ajax is complete
}
```

This will ensure that you have fired only one `scan` at any given point of time.

> I don't clear the timeout at all and don't use the $timeout . is it
>   mistake ? is it cause to chrome problem like freezing or CPU overhead?

Since you are only firing one `scan` at any point of time and that too after first one is complete, I don't see how this will create any CPU overhead.

Comment: And as I do it know it can be a problem ? the page is without refreshing for example 3 days  and evrey 1 second the timer is fierd

Comment: @Guz Didn't understand this *And as I do it know it can be a problem ?* Can you rephrase?

Comment: i have page that working without refresh or move to another route , and the timer is fired every 1 second,  I want to make sure it wont be a problem to my computer or CPU or browser without clean it or smth

Comment: @Guz You were not only firing the scan every second, you were potentially firing multiple scans at any given point in time - which was totally useless. Ideally whether it will be a problem for your CPU or not depends upon how CPU intensive that scan is.

Comment: if there is issue with one of the request there will not be scan anymore. 
and if the timeout is out of the scanComplete the timer will continue to work  and when the server will be up it return to work  
so I done know if it is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to *$destroy* event in your root controller and call a public method of your service that clears the timeout:

```js
module.factory("myService", function($scope, $timeout) {
     
  var timer;
     
  function scan (id) {    
    // $http......
    timer = setTimeout(function() {scan())}, 1000);
  }

  function destroyTimer() {
      if (timer) {
          $timeout.cancel(timer);
      }
  }
 
  return {
     destroyTimer: destroyTimer,
     // ...
  }

});

module.controller("RootController", function($scope, $timeout, myService) {
  $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
      myService.destroyTimer();
  });
});
```

Comment: my timer is in the service and not controller, or should i return the promise to the controller. 

also, how can I know that the destory was fired?

Comment: And when the destroy will be fiered ?